# How to maintain instance number in list of objects

Tags: c#, list, class, object, instance

I have a class `baseClass`, and a list of objects of the `baseClass`. What i want to achieve is that i **have to dynamically assign the instance number to each object in the list.** for that what am doing is that use a constructor to do this.

Following is the class definition:

```
public class baseClass
{
    private int _InstanceNumber;
    private int _MyIntVal;
    private string _MyString;
    public string MyString
    {
        get { return _MyString; }
        set { _MyString = value; }
    }
    public int MyIntVal
    {
        get { return _MyIntVal; }
        set { _MyIntVal = value; }
    }
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return _InstanceNumber; }
    }
    public baseClass(int instance)
    {
        _InstanceNumber = instance;
    }
}
```

The creation of the List of objects is as follows:

```
int instanceNumber = 0;
List<baseClass> classList = new List<baseClass>();
classList.Add(new baseClass(instanceNumber++) { MyString = "sample1", MyIntVal = 10 });
classList.Add(new baseClass(instanceNumber++) { MyString = "sample2", MyIntVal = 11 });
```

I know it is not the actual way for creating this. it does not give the index number actually. how can i calculate the instance number?

Consider the following scenario, that am creating another list of objects then it hard to maintain the instance number. or if i create another object(this also be an instance) external to the list.

```
int instanceNumber = 0;
List<baseClass> anotherClassList = new List<baseClass>();
classList.Add(new baseClass(instanceNumber++) { MyString = "sample1", MyIntVal = 10 });
classList.Add(new baseClass(instanceNumber++) { MyString = "sample2", MyIntVal = 11 });
```

**Updates:**
This is my temporary solution for this. i need proper way/ method to maintain instance number

Comment: " it does not give the index number actually" - what do you mean? By the way, you should look into automatically-implemented properties, which can significantly reduce the amount of code you need to write - particularly with C# 6, which supports automatically-implemented read-only properties. I'd also strongly recommend that you review .NET naming conventions.

Comment: Next, what about if you create a new list - would you expect those instance numbers to start again from 0? Or is this a *global* instance number?

Comment: Your code works for me...

Comment: " it does not give the index number actually" What happens? Wich error are you finding? Please, explain better

Comment: You may not to store an instance number, but get it from `List<T>` with help of the method `IndexOf`. `var list = new List<BaseClass>(); var a = new BaseClass(); list.Add(a); var b = new BaseClass(); list.Add(b); int numberOfA = list.IndexOf(a);`

Comment: @ john skeet :this is actually my question is. how can i maintain these number

Comment: all: please see my updates

Comment: hai all, the answers will not solve my issue, i have made updations in the question please go through that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the index of item in the list, you should ask it from the `list`, not the `item` like:

```
var index = list.IndexOf(item);
```

But it seems that you expect the `item` **to be aware of its position** in the `list`. In order to do this, you should pass the `list` to the `item` so it can use it to find its own place in it:

```
public class Item
{
    private List<Item> _containerList;

    public Item(List<Item> containerList)
    {
        _containerList = containerList;
    }

    public int InstanceNumber
    {
        get { return _containerList.IndexOf(this); }
    }
}
```

and change your code to:

```
List<Item> classList = new List<Item>();
classList.Add(new Item(classList ) { ... });
classList.Add(new Item(classList ) { ... });
```